# python/Tensorflow/keras/opencv -(fmri dataset) why my X_train result shows 0 ? Is that means my image not input to training?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras

```
imgs = []
mypath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\fmri_deep_learning\\origin"
all_img_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(mypath, "*.tif"))

for img_path in all_img_paths:
    img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
    img = img.astype('float32')/255.
    imgs.show(img)

X = np.array(imgs)    
X_train = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 64, 256, 1)
X_test = X_train.copy()

print("X_train:", X_train.shape)
```

I want to load images in `my_path`file, and then output `X_train`, but my result is `X_train: (0, 64, 256, 1)`,I don't know why `X_train` is `0`?

sorry for my poor English!!

How to use for loop to write the code?

```
imgs=[10*64*265]
for i=1 to 10
read img;show;img
imgs(cut , : , : )=img
end

print imgs,shape
```

Please give me some advice, thanks!!

Comment: Is this line `imgs.show(img)` correct ?

Comment: The line`imgs.show(img)`  I change to `imgs.append(img)`,but the answer  of `X_train` also is 0.